# Stripe's price calculation info to the client app

Tags: stripe-payments

We have a lot of products in our dashboard; each product has just one price.
Each product's price has a *graduated pricing* model, so if users buy more units they pay less for each unit.

The only way we found to know how much users have to pay is to create the subscription for a given quantity of products so that the invoice will give us the amount.

Is there a way for extracting the graduated pricing ranges for sending it to the client app? We'd like to avoid creating a subscription to know the final price for the given number of units; also, we'd like to avoid replicating the pricing model's logic on our backend.

Comment: You can retrieve an upcoming invoice(https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming) without needing an existing subscription(just pass `subscription_items`), which lets you preview a subscription's first payment before creating it, so I'd maybe see if that works for your use case.

Comment: This partially solves our problem, since we don't need to create an invoice every time users want to check the final price. But this involves continuously asking our backend which is the price for the selected quantity. Thanks!

Comment: Any final solution here?

Comment: getting the tiers for each product price. When fetching prices don't forget to extend the API with e.g "data.tiers". Calculation would be client side with the tier information provided :)